# Distribute Enterprise app through existing App on iTunes (regular program)

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, ios-enterprise

Been searching through the forum without much luck.

I have an [app on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/mobilforbrug/id760907918?mt=8&uo=4existing) that help users find the best mobile subscription plan based on their usage - and usage estimated by uploading picture from settings.

The plan is to create an enterprise version, and was wondering if it is possible to distribute the enterprise version through the existing one via a button in the app. (i.e. when clicking it automatically downloads the enterprise app).

Do you know if it is possible, and have you seen others doing the same thing?
And do you know if there are any limitations to the model? (if it is possible)

Comment: When you say you want to distribute an Enterprise version, do you mean an ad hoc distribution as part of Apple's Enterprise Developer Program, or simply a different App Store version of the app with an enterprise focus?

Comment: @Cilius according apple u should not distribute the enterprise application outside your enterprise, its illegal accord to apple.

Comment: Ad hoc distribution of a similar app, but one that retrieves a few more information then what is possible with the ordinary license.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise distribution can not be done like that and its own kinda provisioning for distribution, you have to take the member for the enterprise distribution programme and create new binary for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise apps are only for in-house app development. For example IBM wants to make an internal mail app that logs into their private servers. Distributing to customers is in breach of the agreement and your account would be removed if you attempted this.